# WPF Button Status?

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I am work on login page in my WPF application, I want the background image for login keypad buttons to change to two different states,not press (Default)show in image background (keypad_button.png), when pressed(IsPressed)(keypad_button_pressed.png). i tried to make this, and i succeeded to make the background button change when i pressed it (IsPressed Trigger), but the problem is in default background image ??

How to make default background image for button is appear, then when i pressed the button it change to another background image ?

Here's my Style :

```
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    CornerRadius="1"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RestaurantPOS;component/images/buttons/keypad_button_pressed.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                        </Trigger>                         
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

This is my keypad buttons : (the style only applied on button number 7)

[image]

```
    <Button x:Name="txb7" Click="txb7_Click" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Height="57" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"></Button>
```

as you shewing, button number 7 default background don't appear(blue), but when i pressed it the (keypad_button_pressed.png) is work. how can i solve this issue.

I Do not want to used ToggleButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write one more trigger to check `IsPressed` is false and in this trigger you can set default image.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border Name="border" 
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
    CornerRadius="1"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RestaurantPOS;component/images/buttons/keypad_button_pressed.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/RestaurantPOS;component/images/buttons/keypad_button.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>                         
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```